# How to make webpage responsive in IOS hybrid application?

Tags: android, ios, hybrid-mobile-app, responsive

I am working on a hybrid application.
My webpages are responsive when i check them in browser inspect window on iphone screen.
But when when i used them in ios, it does not remain responsive anymore.
Any idea about problem and solution?

The same issue is resolved in android by first zooming out the page and the zoom in according to screen size. But it is not working here.

Comment: I'll take a wild guess, are you using viewport meta tag that is required for mobile browsers? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: No, i am not using it.

Comment: Well, you need to. You can find detailed information of why you need on the link I posted in the first comment.